# "Increasingly XXX" or "increasingly more XXX"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

Which is correct: *increasingly XXX* or *increasingly more XXX*, where *XXX* is an adjective? A colleague and I are disagreeing. I think the use of *more* is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

If people are *more aware* of something, then their awareness of it is greater than it was at some time in the past. If they’re *increasingly aware* of it, then the rate of growth of their awareness is accelerating. If they are *increasingly more aware* of it, then the rate of accelertion of their awareness is itself increasing.

Comment: I would say that "increasingly more aware" instead implies that the fraction of the people whose awareness is increasing, is also increasing.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I agree - grammatically it's probably nonsense, but when we see *"increasingly more"* in the context of people's awareness, we tend to assume not only that the number of people who are aware is increasing, but the ones who are already aware are becoming *more aware*. Or alternatively more people are becoming aware and their levels of awareness are increasing - it doesn't really make much difference since both ways round we're assuming there are two things on the rise at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Although *increasingly more* seems popular, none of *increasingly*'s examples [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increasingly) include *more*:

> People are becoming *increasingly* aware of this problem.
>   *Increasingly*, scientists are questioning the data.
>   The situation grew *increasingly* hopeless.

Tacking on *more* adds the same sort of redundancy discussed in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/increasingly-positive-or-increasingly-comparative).